# Detach face through UV

Tags: modeling, uv

can we detach faces from the object through UV editor
What I want is to select the poly through UV and then detach them from the geometry

Answer (score 2):

Sure. The easiest way is probably to enable the “UV Sync Selection” option, which is the button that looks like two diagonal arrows at the top left of the UV editor:

[image]

This will synchronize your UV selection with the selection of geometry in the 3D viewport. Then you can just select whichever faces you want to separate in the UV editor, move your mouse cursor to the 3D viewport, and press <kbd>Y</kbd> to split the faces within a single object or <kbd>P</kbd> to separate the faces into a new object.

Comment: Wow..so simple...thankyou you save me a ton of work